# Haxe classes seem to use the filename, not the class name

Tags: haxe

I have a file called `1-DarknessScene.hx` which contains `class DarknessScene`. When I try to reference this by creating a fully-qualified `new com.foo.bar.scenes.DarknessScene()`, I get a `class not found` error.

I double-checked the [class/instance docs](http://haxe.org/manual/types-class-instance.html), but found no references to this behaviour.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section in the manual you are looking for is this:

http://haxeorg.dev/manual/type-system-modules-and-paths.html

In Haxe, each ".hx" file is called a module, and it can contain one or more classes, typedefs, enums, interfaces etc.  A few points:

- Usually, the file name / module name is the same as that of the main class.  So  `DarknessScene.hx`, rather than `1-DarknessScene.hx`.
- This means your file names have the class naming rules apply, so they must begin with an upper-case letter, not a number.  In your case if you want to have a number to sort the files, you might name you class "Scene01Darkness" or something similar.
- The manual describes how you can have different types (classes, interfaces etc) inside a module, and reference them.  A quick example:

Scenes.hx

```
package mygame;

class Scene01Darkness {
    // ...
}
```

And then import like this:

```
new mygame.Scenes.Scene01Darkness();
```

But the rules about class names (and I guess filenames) beginning with an upper case character  still apply.

Good luck!